# Adding unique Event Listener for an each td in table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend, addeventlistener

The objective of the code is for each block to display a different text when the mouse is over it. I want to add 30 more blocks to this but I cant seem to find a way to do this without having to create a different Event Listener for each block. Is it possible to do this with a single event listener for mouseover and mouseout using arrays and for loops?
This is what the Javascript and HTML code looks like V

```js
var org = ["Anna", "Bob", "Caroline"]
var change = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

var headone = document.querySelector("#a");
headone.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  headone.textContent = change[0];
})
headone.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  headone.textContent = org[0];
})


var headtwo = document.querySelector("#b");
headtwo.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  headtwo.textContent = change[1];
})
headtwo.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  headtwo.textContent = org[1];
})

var headthree = document.querySelector("#c");
headthree.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  headthree.textContent = change[2];
})
headthree.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  headthree.textContent = org[2];
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>

  <style>
    table {
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    td {
      width: 20%;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    td:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      margin-top: 100%;
    }
    
    td:hover {
      background-color: pink;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 24px 5px rgba(129, 120, 255, 1);
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="a">Anna</td>
      <td id="b">Bob</td>
      <td id="c">Caroline</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Is there any way I can code the Javascript section to be more efficient using arrays? Instead having to create a new EventListener for every new block I add to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sort of indexation where the id of every element will determine it's org & change value. Take a look at the following code:

```
var org = ["Anna", "Bob", "Caroline"],
    change = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

var test = document.querySelectorAll('td');

// Loop to set id's and add eventlisteners 
for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
    test[i].id = i;
    test[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        test[i].textContent = change[i];
    });
    test[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        test[i].textContent = org[i];
    });
}
```

This code works the way I think you want it to.

This snippet however, is based on in wich order they are placed in the code. You'll see when you play around with it :)

Comment: Oh Wow! Thank you very much, I've been struggling for the last 2 days trying to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function, which adds the two event listeners. Then I would grab the table row and iterate over it's children. Each iteration runs the function, which adds the event listeners.

```
function addEventListeners(target, index) {
    target.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        target.textContent = change[index];
    });
    target.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        target.textContent = org[index];
    });
}

var trChilds = document.querySelector('tr').children;
for (let index = 0; index < trChilds.length; index++) {
    const element = trChilds[index];
    addEventListeners(element, index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `class` to your `td` elements and then use `document.querySelectorAll()` to return an array of all elements with that class.

Then you can use the `forEach()` method to apply changes to all of them at once. You just have to make sure that your `change` array has the same amount of elements as the `td` elements you're rendering on the page.

```js
var org = ["Anna", "Bob", "Caroline"]
var change = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

const refs = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

refs.forEach((ref, i) => {
    ref.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        ref.textContent = change[i]
    })

    ref.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        ref.textContent = org[i];
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>

  <style>
    table {
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    td {
      width: 20%;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    td:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      margin-top: 100%;
    }
    
    td:hover {
      background-color: pink;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 24px 5px rgba(129, 120, 255, 1);
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="a" class="box">Anna</td>
      <td id="b" class="box">Bob</td>
      <td id="c" class="box">Caroline</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
give all td class of tds and then write the following code.


let tabs=document.querySelectorAll(".tds");
let i=0;
tabs.forEach(e=>{
    e.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
        e.textContent=change[i];
    })
    e.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
        e.textContent=org[i];
    })
    i++
})
```